# How to compare all changed files between two git tags in PhpStorm?

Tags: git, phpstorm

I'm trying to figure out what changes were made between two git tags in a repository (namely [the Bootstrap repository](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap)).

I want to know which files have changed in the new `v4.0.0-alpha.6` compared to the previous `v4.0.0-alpha.5`. I also want to diff some of the files to inspect the changes.

On the command line I'm using

```
git diff v4.0.0-alpha.5..v4.0.0-alpha.6
```

or

```
git difftool v4.0.0-alpha.5..v4.0.0-alpha.6
```

To launch vimdiff for each file.

Can this be done in PhpStorm as well? I've only been able to find information on comparing the whole project between branches, but I want to compare between two tags.